# SQL - Can't add new foreign key constraint on SQL Fiddle

Tags: sql, reference, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm working on SQL Fiddle and code so far looks like this:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` ( 
`id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `customerID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `paymentAmmount` float(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_customers_customerID` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`)
    REFERENCES `customers` (`customerID`) );
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` ( 
`id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` ( 
`customerID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  #`accountId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items-orders` ( 
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `itemId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `orderId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `itemQuantity` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
  KEY `FK_items_itemId` (`itemId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_items_itemId` FOREIGN KEY (`itemId`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` ( 
`id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `passwordHash` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There are two lines that don't work:

```html
 KEY `FK_customers_customerID` (`customerID`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_customers_customerID` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to link the 'customerID' var in the 'orders' table to the same var in the 'customers' table.
It worked with the 'items-orders' and 'items' table, but now I keep getting this message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY `FK_customers_customerID` (`customerID`), CONSTRAINT `FK_customers_customer' at line 1
```

I really don't know how to fix this, any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Code snippets are for html/css/javascript. Just use a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key in customers is `CustomerId`, so you need to use that:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_customers_customerID` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`)
    REFERENCES `customers` (`customerID`)
```

Comment: I added your line to the code, but now I get an error message that says: Cannot add foreign key constraint. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: NVM, I just had to add the orders table after the customers table, ty for your help ^^